# Is it possible to return a HTTP request to apache after php processing?

Tags: php, apache, http

What I want to do is the following:

1. A User initates a HTTP GET request for a static file (for example an image or an mp3 file for HTML5 audio)
2. A PHP script intercepts these requests (for example via mod_rewrite) and checks the cookie for valid authentification
3. If successful, the file is delivered to the User, or the User gets a 401

Now, it would be perfect and most simple if the PHP script could "pass through" a successful request and return control to Apache, so that Apache can deliver the file as if it was the original request. Since we have also caching and the need to deliver audio files (including chunked requests) this would free the php script from manually creating the response headers etc.

Is this possible at all?

And if not, what would be the easiest, simplest solution to achieve this, so that caching and (chunked) requests for audio files still works as intended?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use AJAX.

Comment: or you want to use an auth class for dealing with files

Comment: Nope, no AJAX please. Especially with audio files I do not want to use that route. Should be simple "vanilla" requests from the client point of view, ie using <img src=...> as well as <audio src=....>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is [X-Sendfile](http://www.jasny.net/articles/how-i-php-x-sendfile/).

Indeed, you can use mod_rewrite to let PHP deal with whatever-mime files, and then return an error or the wanted file via the X-Sendfile header (note that you’ll have to activate the eponymous module within apache).

Didn’t test it though. It seems to be a pretty important issue. OwnCloud, for example, still use PHP to serve files...

Comment: Yes, this might be the solution I am looking for, as this mod seems to support cache control as well as ranged requests. OK, but is it secure as well? Of course only the php script should be able to initiate this, and it should not be possible to do it remotely. Any other things we have to take care of then?

Comment: I don’t think the x-sendfile module was made to be used by anything but a server-side script language. Thus, the security is merely you: the way you code and administrate your server. However, it’s been years since this project was updated, I consider it is wise for you to investigate a little... But be reassured: according to google, this mod doesn’t seem to be a well-knowed security hole.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gui-Don! That should help.